# Выборка данных из бд через массив

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Мне требуется сформировать отчет в excel
В него должны попасть все выделенные поля 
Я собираю их в массив (поля id) и по клику формирую ссылку

```
let selectedItems = new Array()
$('input[name="id_check"]:checked').each(function () {
selectedItems.push($(this).val())
})
location.href = 'report/'+selectedItems;
```

Вопрос в том, как мне выбрать из бд все поля в с моими id
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ну если прям в таком виде передавать поля, то нужно сделать маршрут вида
`Route::get('report/{fields}', 'ReportController@index');`.
Вытащить их в контроллере и указать в выборке

```
public function index(Request $request, $fields){
  $result = Model::get(explode(',', $fields));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Превратить массив в строку, где каждый элемент разделён запятой: `selectedItems.join(",")`, отправить на сервер (например - через [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)), и сделать выборку:
`$items = DB::table('table')->whereIn('id', $data)->get()` (пример с использованием [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries), поскольку в метках - laravel)